# blob stream Length property value always -1, no matter the file empty or not

Tags: c#, azure, blob, storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a code that opens a stream for a blob on storage to read its content (steps described below), the blob is a Json file which is sometimes empty, it appears on azure portal with 0B, and can be downloaded and opened.

I check the blobStream.Length property to know if it's an empty blob or not for handling the file, for some reason no matter if the file empty or not the Length property is -1 and not 0.

I have read at some places that the -1 is the initialized value of the property, and that FetchAttributesAsync must be called in order to update the metadata .. and I read on Microsoft docs that calling OpenReadAsync automatically calls FetchAttributesAsync, mentioned in these docs under remarks:

[OpenReadAsyncDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.openreadasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_OpenReadAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

[FetchAttributesAsyncDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.fetchattributesasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_FetchAttributesAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_OperationContext_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

not sure what's happening, whether the problem is with the FetchAttributes call or something with opening the stream, and why the Length is -1 always.

I use Azure.Storage.Blobs, to create a blob client with the connection string and return the blob stream to read its content

```
_blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
blobStream = await _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container).GetBlobClient(blobName).OpenReadAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

on the stream returned from OpenReadAsync we check the length .. and handle the file:

`if( blobStream.Length == 0 ) continue;` < -- the length is -1 always

Comment: Is the code you posted really what you're actually using? Because I would expect to see an `await` somewhere.

Comment: I didn't copy past I wrote what I did in general, any way edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the blob file as stream, [`BlobBaseClient.DownloadTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.downloadto?view=azure-dotnet) method will help.

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobName);
MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
blob.DownloadTo(s);
Console.WriteLine(s.Length);
```

And there is another way to get the length of the blob's content with [`BlobProperties.ContentLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobproperties.contentlength?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobProperties_ContentLength).

```
BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobName);
var properties = blob.GetProperties();
Console.WriteLine(properties.Value.ContentLength);
```

Comment: this was helpful, thank you :D, I took the other way with getting blob properties then opening read stream accordingly if the content is 0 or not.

i also opened an issue to storage hope that get's taken care of if it's a bug.